# Send client certificate from portable class library

Tags: c#, httpclient, portable-class-library

Is there any way to use client certificate with PCL? With portable HttpClient or any other way?
Thank you!

Comment: did you solve it somehow?

Comment: Kind of. Will give more details on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make generic PCL HttpClient to use client certificate. But you can implement your custom MessageHandler for each platform and pass it to the HttpClient's constructor.
For Xamarin iOS and Android you can make use of ModernHttpClietnt (it's open source) and on WP the only way to implement client certificate is to use SSL BlackBox (which is not free).
On other platforms (like WinRT) it's even simpler to achive this goal.

Comment: Is it possible to use the protocolFilter in WP instead of SSL blackbox? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878566/client-certificates-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: In Windows Phone 8 Silverlight App - no, in Windows Phone 8.1 App - probably yes. My app is Silverlight one and that is the problem.