# C# signing Soap Header in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, soap, windows-phone

We have the need to call a server with Soap with signed timestamp header on a Windows 8.1 phone. We are using VS Community 2015 as our dev environment. The webservice site has provided us with certificate to sign with. No username/password is to be used.

We have tried to use the code generated from adding a Service Reference from the wsdl file but have not found how to sign the header. As we try to run the call we get an "InvalidOperationException" with text saying we need to supply username. If we then supply a random username/password in the ClientCredentials we get MessageSecurityException with text "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."

Has anyone managed to use a certificate to sign a time stamped soap header on Windows 8.1 phone? Noticed that most pages on MSDN for soap clients are page not found.

After this we looked around for examples of signing soap request header in c#. In following what code examples do we have not found that the System.Security.Cryptography.XML package is not available. Does anyone know where XmlDsigC14NTransform was moved or what a replacement would be for getting the DigestValue for the timestamp in the soap header?

Bottom line question on this would be does anyone have example of how to perform a soap request with a timestamped soap header that works on windows 8.1 phone?

Following is what we have tried. Names and addresses etc changed

```
        SoapWS.myRequest req = new SoapWS.myRequest();
        // setup the request fields


        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
        binding.Namespace = "urn:<the name space>";
        binding.Name = "<name of binding>";
        TransportSecurityBindingElement securityElement = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
        securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;


        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(<from loaded bytes>);

        binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
        binding.Elements.Add(securityElement);
        binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

        SoapWS.myRequestClient client = new SoapWS.myRequestClient(
            binding,
            addr);

        //client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
        //client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "admin";

        using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            // Add a SOAP Header to an outgoing request
            MessageHeader aMessageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", binding.Namespace, cert);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(aMessageHeader);
        }

        client.myRequestCompleted += Client_completed;
        client.myRequestSessionAsync(req);
```

Comment: The following answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24338216/1721022

Comment: thanks tlango that answer can help in loading the x509 certificate but still missing the ability to conicalize and sign the timestamp on windows phone 8.1 still searching for libs to try and do this.