# Windows Phone 8 and HTTPS/SSL

Tags: windows-phone-8, ssl, https, windows-phone-8.1

I need to connect to a web service via HTTPS in my windows phone 8.0 app. It seems that there is no client SSL support from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533) about this issue.

I really need to know how to deal with certificates in WP8. What is the correct certificate? Which certificates need to be imported?

Scenario: I have a https endpoint: `https://10.1.1.2` and when I connect there from my PC I am being prompted to view and install the certificate of the server. The certificate name "The Root CA" is being saved locally. The same certificate is installed in the mobile device w/o problems. When I open the `https://10.1.1.2` from the *mobile internet explorer* it informs me that the web page is secure and I have to choose between close and continue the page. I am clicking continue and the `https://10.1.1.2` transaction takes place. Every time I go to the same URL via the *mobile internet explorer* there is no warning to the end user regarding security.

> According to Microsoft: In most cases, you do not have to do anything
>   to enable this for your Windows Phone app with the exception of using
>   an address that begins with the https:// protocol scheme. Windows
>   Phone then examines the certificate that is returned by the web
>   service, and if the certificate is from one of the trusted authorities
>   listed in SSL root certificates for Windows Phone OS 7.1, the Windows
>   Phone app platform then uses the certificate in conjunction with the
>   web service to encrypt all further communication, including the
>   exchange of the authentication credentials as described previously.
>   Although you can install trusted certificates on the Windows Phone, in
>   the current release, the Windows Phone app platform does not expose
>   those certificates’ values to apps. As a result, in the current
>   release, you cannot implement mutual authentication scenarios –
>   scenarios in which the client sends its own certificates to the web
>   service in addition to receiving one -- using certificates installed
>   in the root store.

So, is this procedure OK? I cannot use one of the certificate authorities that Microsoft
trusts by default. Do I need code?

Comment: Did you try adding the SSL through the Manifest file?

Just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041207

Comment: @anonshankar Is this the server certificate?

Comment: nop it's a client side one.

Comment: @anonshankar have you ever tried to work with client certificates in WP8? Did it work?

Comment: The problem is known to me, i haven't had any luck with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290505/httpclient-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app

Comment: If the certificates you are using is a valid digitally signed one for your SSL connection, then there is nothing that is to be done for this issue, i had same issue and have tried out all the scenario you have mentioned but falied, finally discovered it was issue with the certificate. We used a self signed certificate with our webservices. Later when we bought a valid certificate, the issue was resolved, there was no codding or manifest changes required.

Comment: ^This, you need to obtain a valid ssl certificate and include it as appropriate. Self signed certificate might be invalid or flagging as such.

Comment: @Is there any work around for this , in my scenario the api is not in my control and did not have a valid certificate , can i provide a certificate locally in the application

Answer (score 1):

Self signed certificate cannot be used and it does not automatically fetch data without intervention.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when testing your SSL connection through mobile IE, it appears from my testing that by pressing continue you are adding an exception to IE, not installing any certificates or getting the exception to apply phone-wide.

Secondly, using self-signed certificates on WP8 appears to be severely limited by the fact that any cert chain that does not use a built-in root CA will generate a failed certificate  validation in your code. See the MSDN blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2010/12/30/wp7-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates.aspx

Where he states "You can implement your own certificate authority using Microsoft Certificate Services but you’ll still need a certificate from one of the phone’s certificate authorities to chain your certificate authority to."

The only "solution" I've seen posted is to effectively ignore all certificate warnings - which is no solution at all.